# How to create UI elements lazily in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

We are creating a WPF application which makes heavy use of highly decorated input elements. A simple example of decorated element is a TextBox which looks like a read-only TextBlock when it doesn't have focus, and turns into a TextBox after receiving focus. Also, additional visual feedback is provided when the changed value is being saved to database. The problem is that showing a view that contains lots of these elements (let's say 100) is very slow and makes application very unresponsive.

We have implemented this decorator as UserControl which contains all required elements (for example the TextBlock to show unfocused text and rotating image for busy indicator). Then we add the input element as child of this decorator control, meaning that in addition to all extra elements, the decorator also contains the input element in its visual tree. In XAML this would look like:

```
<custom:Decorator Context="{Binding ValueHelper}" >
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueHelper.Text}"/>
</custom:Decorator>
```

This makes it easy for us to decorate any input element we want, be it either text box, date picker, combobox or any custom element.

**Now back to the problem**: let's say we have a view which contains 100 decorated text boxes and we navigate to that view. What happens? At least my quad-core laptop freezes for a long time because it has to create many hundred text blocks, rectangles, images etc. to provide the visual feedback for every decorated element, although *no decorations are visible yet*. What really would be required is only 100 TextBlocks because that's what is visible on the screen. It is only after element receives mouse over event or focus when other elements are needed. Also, only one element is being edited at a time, so only one input element (in this case, textbox) would be enough for the whole application.

*So, what would be the best way to achieve same decorations without creating all decorating elements (or the actual input element) for every element in the view?*

---

An example of decorated TextBox to clarify use-case:

The text box looks like a read-only TextBlock when it does not have focus or mouse cursor is not currently on top of it (state 1). Also, three dots ("...") are shown because element does not currenly have any value.

When mouse cursor is moved on top of the element, a dotted green rectangle appears around TextBlock to indicate that element can be modified (state 2). The color would be red if TextBox happened to be read-only.

After receiving focus element turns into actual TextBox which can be used to modify the actual value (state 3).

The value is stored into database after textbox loses its focus, and to show that the value is currently being saved a busy indicator appears to left side of element (state 4).

Finally, the value has been saved and element returns to its idle state showing the new value (state 5). (Actually the elements have even more states related to validation and other specific requirements but you certainly got the point that elements really are highly decorated.)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of drawing all the UI elements upfront, only draw the ones needed

WPF allows you to modify the `Template` of an object using a `DataTrigger`, so you can adjust the template for your Decorator based on your triggers

An example style for your Decorator might look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <!-- Default Template -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
            Value="{StaticResource NoDecoratorTemplate}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource BlankTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource MouseOverTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource FocusedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Property="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource LoadingTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also, WPF shouldn't load non-visible items. You can try setting your decorators `Visibility="Collapsed"` as a test to see if that fixes load time.

If it does and you don't want to go the `Template` route, you could ensure that the `Visibility` of all your objects is set to `Collapsed` to begin with, and they only get set to `Visible` when they should be displayed.

If it doesn't fix your load time, then your problem is probably somewhere else. For example, it looks like some of your decorator items are sized according to the content control placed inside of it, so it's possible what's actually slowing you down isn't displaying the objects, but determining the size of the objects.

Comment: Thank you! Control templates are definitely the way to go with decorating elements. However, this doesn't fix the problem with actual input element. TextBox is our lightest element and we have much heavier custom input elements (e.g. date picker) which we cannot afford to create. We have already set visibility to collapsed but still the visual tree is created and all related resources are loaded which causes serious performance problems.

Comment: @user544511 When you say "all related resources are loaded", do you mean each decorator is loaded? Because if you're using a single UI control for the Decorator and swapping out the Template, you should not get that behavior because only one element exists in the Visual Tree at a time

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation and couldn't reply earlier. I meant that the actual input element (which is a child of decorator, e.g date picker or TextBox) is created, all its resources (including child elements) are loaded and added to visual tree (even if it is collapsed). This causes huge performance hit because date picker is much heavier element than e.g. a TextBox.